# Traveling To Iran with an expired passport

Tags: air-travel, passports, paperwork

My passport expired about 3 months ago and I have a ticket with KLM to go back to Iran. Iranians are allowed to enter Iran with an expired passport, but I just wanted to know is I am allowed to connect through Amsterdam without any problems?

Answer (score 6):

Salam, I travelled this route in June 2017 with an expired passport. The KLM staff at the gate had doubts at first but after a quick 1-minute talk with the supervisor, they let me board the aircraft without any issues. According to Iran, it is absolutely no issue to enter with an expired passport, I have done it many times.

Be only sure to renew your passport while being in Iran if you want to exit the country again, it should be a quick process.

Wishing you a nice trip to Iran.

Answer (score 3):

Edit following the answer by @Amin:

KLM has no obligation to let you board with an expired passport.

Per their [General Conditions of Carriage](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/images/General_Conditions_of_Carriage_2016-September_Global_English_tcm638-430603.pdf) (emphasis mine)

> ARTICLE 9: REFUSAL AND LIMITATION ON CARRIAGE
>   The Carrier may refuse to transport Passengers and their Baggage, if one or more of the following cases has occurred or is likely to occur:
>   [...]
>   (k) The **Passenger does not appear to be in possession of valid travel documents**, may seek or has
>   sought to illegally enter a country through which he may be in transit, or for which he does not
>   have a valid entry document, has destroyed travel documents during the flight, has refused to
>   allow copies thereof to be made and kept by the Carrier, or **the Passenger’s travel documents have
>   expired**, are incomplete in light of the regulations in force, or appear to be fraudulent or otherwise
>   suspicious (for example: identity theft, forgery or counterfeiting of documents).
>
> [...]
>
> 18.2 Travel Documents
>   [...]
>   (b) The Carrier reserves the right, in accordance with Article 9, to refuse the Carriage if a
>   Passenger fails to comply with the applicable laws and regulations, if the Carrier has doubts as to
>   the validity of the documents presented, or the Passenger does not permit the Carrier to take and
>   retain copies of any documents or otherwise retain data contained in the relevant documents.

I tweeted them and their response was quick & clear:

> We will only accept passengers travelling with a valid travel document. An expired passport is not valid anymore.

To be on the safe side I suggest you contact your nearest embassy and try to obtain a new passport or an emergency travel document.

However apparently they **can** let you board at their discretion.

Comment: Is this something their twitter team really knows? It sounds like the kind of default answer they would give expecting that expired passport = document not acceptable anywhere; whereas a Station Manager would actually look at TIMATIC and make an informed decision. I'm not saying it's definitely wrong but for this kind of slightly nuanced question I personally would not trust social media.

Comment: @Calchas please see my edit, does that satisfy your concerns?

Comment: What if there is no Iranian embassy in the country where OP is currently located?

Comment: @Szabolcs that is an interesting question but not part of this question. In such cases either another country's embassy provides consular assistance (e.g. Sweden for the US in North Korea) or there is a consulate that can issue emergency documents for travel to the next embassy (e.g. for Australian citizens in Ukraine to the embassy in Poland). This is AFAIK and not part of the original question, OP would need to specify where they are currently located and their visa/immigration status there.

Comment: @mts It's a stronger authority, thanks for looking it up. It's interesting that even here they won't give a definitive declaration, such as "we refuse to carry", rather a "may refuse", suggesting that if you speak to the right person it could happen. On that basis, I would agree it's good advice to get the passport renewed if possible, so I'll upvote this answer, but I'd say if you've not got any other options, get to the airport early and be persistent.

Comment: @Calchas I noticed that as well, and so theoretically they could allow to board. However (and especially given their clear statement on twitter) I consider the possibility of this to be only theoretical (i.e. nil) and best advice to the OP really is to get a new passport at any possible cost.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IR&selDest=Iran&TR=NL&selTrans=Netherlands&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Nationals of Iran are allowed to enter with an expired
>     passport.

Regarding Transit in Amsterdam:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Iran, holding onward
>   tickets transiting For details, click here by the same or first
>   connecting aircraft **AND** meeting one of the following
>   conditions:
>
> - holding a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus,
>     Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom,
>     traveling to any non-Schengen Member State;
> - returning from Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland
>     (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom after having
>     used the visa;

So if you have a visa from one of the mentioned countries, you can transit in Amsterdam on your expired passport. Given that you're not entering the Schengen Area, their entry requirements do not apply to you.

However, if you do **not** hold one of These visas, you will Need a Schengen airside transit visa, and as far as I know, the Dutch embassy won't issue it to an expired passport.

Comment: Timatic doesn't mention passport requirements for transit. Does it mean an expired passport is OK?

Comment: @ugoren It means there is no particular requirement. Put Mauritius as the transit country and you'll see something else.